# Best approach to add borders to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drawrect, quartz-2d

I often need to add borders to edges of UITableViewCell, but the approach I tried seems not quite working well.

First, I created CustomBorderView class, and implemented drawRect to draw specified type of borders to the view.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger,CustomBorderType)
{
    CustomBorderTypeTop,      //Draw a border only at top
    CustomBorderTypeBottom,   //Draw a border only at bottom
    CustomBorderTypeLeft,     //Draw a border only at left
    CustomBorderTypeRight,    //Draw a border only at right
    CustomBorderTypeSides,
    CustomBorderTypeAll,      //Draw a border on all edges
    CustomBorderTypeDottedBottomSolidSides, //Draw a dotted border at bottom and solid    border both sides
    CustomBorderTypeNone      //Cell with no border
};

@interface CustomBorderView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) CustomBorderType borderType;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame borderType:(CustomBorderType)borderType;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [super drawRect:rect];
  /* draw lines in the cell */
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.borderColor.CGColor);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.borderWidth);

  switch (self.borderType)
  {
    ...

    case CustomBorderTypeAll:
        //draw top separator
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2)); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2)); //draw to this point

        //draw left edge line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2), 0.0f); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2), self.bounds.size.height); //draw to this point

        //draw right edge line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width - (self.borderWidth / 2), 0.0f); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width - (self.borderWidth / 2), self.bounds.size.height); //draw to this point

        //draw bottom separator
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height - (self.borderWidth / 2)); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - (self.borderWidth / 2)); //draw to this point
        break;

    case CustomBorderTypeDottedBottomSolidSides:
    {
        //draw left edge line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2), 0.0f); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0f + (self.borderWidth / 2), self.bounds.size.height); //draw to this point

        //draw right edge line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width - (self.borderWidth / 2), 0.0f); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width - (self.borderWidth / 2), self.bounds.size.height); //draw to this point

        //stroke solid line
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        //draw dotted line
        CGFloat dashPattern[] = {1.0, 1.0};
        CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, dashPattern, 2);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0 , self.bounds.size.height -  (DOT_RADIUS / 2)); //start at this point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - (DOT_RADIUS / 2)); //draw to this point

        break;
    }
```

Secondly, add UIViewAutoResizingMaskFlexibleWidth and Height, so that custom view autoresizes when cell bounds changed.

Finally, insert this view below the custom UITableViewCell's contentView.

```
[cell insertSubview:borderView belowSubview:cell.contentView];
```

I actually do this in UITableViewCell subclass.

I thought this is a good way to accomplish what I want because it's reusable and easy to use. I can specify the border type in cellForRowAtIndexPath method for each single rows.

However, somehow the border is sometimes off, disappear, extended when I use cell with dynamic height. Especially for dotted lines, dots are extended to vertical lines.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this issue, or any better approach to accomplish adding borders to views. Thanks in advance!

[image: Extended dotted line]

[image: Off side borders]

[image: Disappeared border]

Comment: Try setting cell.backgroundView = borderView instead of [cell insertSubview:borderView belowSubview:cell.contentView];

Comment: Hi San, thanks for your comment. Setting background view did not fix the problem. I avoided to use backgroundView property because setting backgroundColor of contentView will hide backgroundView.

Comment: can you try - override layoutSubviews in your custom cell and invoke setNeedsDisplay to your border view. Don't forget to call [super layoutSubview]

Comment: Hi San, I actually figured out how to solve this problem. What you suggested is exactly how I fixed. I also removed autoResizingMask and added a line self.customBorderView.frame = self.bounds; before [self.customView setNeedDisplay]; to layoutSubviews. I will update answer when I got time. Thanks!

Comment: @kazuochi do you have the full solution to this? Looking to doing something similar with my cells.

Comment: @Tender I've been using it without issue, so you can probably do the same. Just make sure override layoutSubview to adjust the borderView as described above. Also if I'm rewriting this, I would use bit mask to define border type rather than what I have now.